# Making a text <div> fit into a clip-pathed header image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a header image which uses clip-path to make it's lower section angled like so:

CSS:

```
.angled {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 96%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 96%);
}
```

I then apply this class to any div I want to become angled, which works, however for divs inside that class that contain text, the text does not fit to the newly shaped div. I would like it so the first line- the large title, fits neatly under the angle.

**(note that with codepen, the video doesn't clip for some reason- it works fine locally- this isn't a concern)**

Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/Darlton29/pen/mdeMpKp)

```css
.angled {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 80%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 80%);
}

.angled-inverted {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 80%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 80%, 0 100%);
}


header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  height: 75vh;
  min-height: 25rem;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 0;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

header .container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

header .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 1;
}

@media (pointer: coarse) and (hover: none) {
  header {
    background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/XT5OInaElMw/1600x900') black no-repeat center center scroll;
  }
  header video {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<header>
  <div class="overlay angled"></div>
  <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop" class="angled"> 
    <source src="https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/Mt_Baker.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <div class="container h-100">
    <div class="d-flex h-100 text-center align-items-center">
      <div class="w-100 text-white">
        <h1 class="display-3">Video Header</h1>
        <p class="lead mb-0">With HTML5 Video and Bootstrap 4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

        <section class="angled-inverted" style="background-color: grey; padding-top: -1rem; padding-bottom: 15rem;">
          <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-left: 4rem">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <h1 style="font-size: 45pt">Angled Video Image</h1>
                <p style="font-family:evogriaregular">The HTML5 video element uses an mp4 video as a source. Change the source video to add in your own background! The header text is vertically centered using flex utilities that are build into Bootstrap 4.</p>
                <p>The overlay color can be changed by changing the <code>background-color</code> of the <code>.overlay</code> class in the CSS.</p>
                <p>Set the mobile fallback image in the CSS by changing the background image of the header element within the media query at the bottom of the CSS snippet.</p>
                    <p>Set the mobile fallback image in the CSS by changing the background image of the header element within the media query at the bottom of the CSS snippet.</p>
                    <p>Set the mobile fallback image in the CSS by changing the background image of the header element within the media query at the bottom of the CSS snippet.</p>
                    <p>Set the mobile fallback image in the CSS by changing the background image of the header element within the media query at the bottom of the CSS snippet.</p>
                    <p>Set the mobile fallback image in the CSS by changing the background image of the header element within the media query at the bottom of the CSS snippet.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

`clip path` is not supported, is intended for images not for text,
if you set strict font size it can't change by itself,
*`padding` cannot be negative*,
unit `pt` shouldn't be used
and finally you spread css all around - external, inline arguing each other multi sub-layers
Any of the above cause problems.